# Calculating subaddresses

Tags: cryptography, sub-address

The PR for subaddresses and MRL-0006 say that the value m is calculated as:

```
m = H_s(a, i) or H_s(a || i)
```

I have found another question attempted to find the answer to my same question, however I am not sure if it is up to date and also is not completely specific. ([How is m calculated when generating subaddresses](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7618/how-is-m-calculated-when-generating-subaddresses))

Is this prefix going to be included in the actually v0.12 release? I cannot find any related code in the v0.12 branch on Github. Additionally, is the i value varint encoded? In the code linked at the above question, it looks like it simply would append the two uint32_t values.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have found where I was confused, as the subaddress code was moved the the device directory

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/27a196b1268718dbc41e308c93b35c58f2da2eb4#diff-202edf76a605025eecb843af6b25fe80L114

This seems like a confusing change to me.